# Simple algorithm. Can't get it right

Tags: java, algorithm

**Problem**

> Yraglac recently decided to try out Soylent, a meal replacement drink designed to meet all nutritional requirements for an average adult. Soylent not only tastes great but is also low-cost, which is important for Yraglac as he is currently on a budget. Each bottle provides 400 calories, so it is recommended that an individual should consume 5 bottles a day for 2000 total calories. However, Yraglac is wondering how many bottles he should consume if his daily calorie requirement is not the same as an average adult. He can only consume an integer number of bottles, and needs to consume at least his daily calorie requirement.

**Src:** https://open.kattis.com/problems/soylent

**Input**

The first line contains a single integer T ≤ 1000 giving the number of test cases. Each test case consists of a single line with an integer N (0 ≤ N ≤ 100000), the number of calories Yraglac needs in a day.

**Output**

For each test case, output a single line containing the number of bottles Yraglac needs to consume for the day.

**Sample Input**

`2
2000
1600`

**Sample Output**

`5
 4`

**My attempt**

```
public Soylent() {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int iterations = scan.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        int calories = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println((int) (Math.ceil(calories / 400)));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code seems to print out the correct answer for your input data, given the code you wrote. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: A couple of questions, more info needed I think: Does it compile? Do you have test cases? Do you get output? What I'm trying to say is we have the problem, the expected results and your code, but not *your results* :)

Comment: your code works properly. or are you talking about the fact you get 5.0 instead of 5?

Comment: why don't you print just calorie/400 ?

Comment: I am not sure. At first I thought that the test cases might be wrong but  plenty of people have completed it already.

The code is compiling, my output matches those given in the problem.
I am getting 5 and not 5.0 (since I convert to int)
If I do calorie / 400 it rounds down instead of up.

Comment: Is 'calories' double?

Answer (score 2):

It's going wrong because you are using `int`s in your `Math.ceil` call.

For example, if you run this code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Math.ceil(2500/400));
        System.out.println(Math.ceil(2500/400.0));
    }
}
```

You will get this output:

```
6.0
7.0
```

In the second `Math.ceil` call you actually work with doubles, so the decimals of 2500/400 is not lost.

To make it more clear:

```
int result1 = 2500 / 400; //6.0
int ceiling1 = Math.ceil(result1); //6

double result2 = 2500 / 400; //6.0
int ceiling2 = Math.ceil(result2); //6

double result3 = 2500 / 400.0; //6,25
int ceiling3 = Math.ceil(result3); //7

double result4 = (double) 2500 / 400; //6.25
int ceiling4 = Math.ceil(result4); //7
```

So to fix your code, either make `calories` a double, divide by `400.0` or cast the result of `calories / 400` to `double`.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael_T. said, calories was a double and not an integer. Thanks!

```
public class Soylent {

public Soylent() {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int iterations = scan.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        double calories = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println((int) (Math.ceil(calories / 400)));
    }
}
```